# Can you expand (execute) function inline with bash to use the result for another command's argument?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm making some simple logging tools to use for work and i have a niche problem that i'm trying to solve when typing commands in a shell. I want to, as smoothly as possible, use a function's result for the argument of another command, all while keeping it inline. For example:

```
sudo some-command --output "<my-function>_log.txt"    <tab><tab> =>
sudo some-command --output "2021_project_a_log.txt"
```

I want to expand, or rather execute, my-function while writing some-command. The double tab is just to get the use across, that's what i mean by "inline" but i might be misusing that term. I don't want to split the command, i.e. execute my-function, store the variable or use the stdout, and then type some-command. The functions print meta data basically such as project name, timestamps etc. I will use them to name and store the output from various commands and tools.

These are the ways i've found so far that works:

- I can write "`my-function`_log.txt"
- I can write "$(my-function)_log.txt"

These two can then either be used as is (in which case i cannot check them first) or i can use the shortcut `Ctrl + Alt + E` to use `shell-expand-line` to expand them but this has the following problems that i try to get around:

- All functions (OK) and all aliases (not OK) are expanded
- Quotes are removed and since i will be using this type of expansion for string input that can break things

I don't want to expand all aliases as some of them can be long and unnecessary which will clutter the prompt.

**Question**:

Is there a way to expand, such as with `Ctrl + Alt + E`, only the selected function or the function that's under the cursor or something? Alternatively, can i block certain aliases from being expanded?

Thanks!

Comment: You can 'block' an alias temporarily by using `\alias`, and it will disable it and use the function name. Aliases take precedence over functions with the same name. `type <command>` shows the function. `command <command>` will run the builtin command even if it has an alias and a function with the same name.

Answer (score 2):

Three steps:

1. Define a completion function for your main program (for you is `sudo`)
   File: `_sudo_completions.env`

   ```bsh
   #! /bin/bash

   _sudo_completions()
   {
       local SOME_COMMAND="echo"
       if [[ "${COMP_WORDS[1]}" == "${SOME_COMMAND}" ]]; then
           if [[ "${COMP_WORDS[2]}" == "--output" ]]; then
               if [[ "${COMP_WORDS[3]}" =~ ^\"[^\"]+_log.txt\"$ ]]; then
                   CMD="${COMP_WORDS[3]%_log.txt\"}"
                   CMD="${CMD#\"}"
                   CMD_RESULT=$(${CMD})
                   COMPREPLY="\"${CMD_RESULT}_log.txt\""
               fi
           fi
       fi
   }

   complete -F _sudo_completions sudo
   ```

   Of course, change value of "`SOME_COMMAND`" variable with your "`sudo`" sub-command.
2. Load this precedent file

   ```bsh
   . _sudo_completions.env
   ```

   You can put this line in your `.bash_profile` file
3. Use it!

   ```bsh
   sudo echo --output "my_fct_log.txt" <tab> <tab>
   ```